# Maya Python: matching the bounding boxes of two different objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I have two objects that will always have random different bounding box sizes, particularly heights. But both will have the pivot at the origin.

I want to match, via scaling, one objects bounding box height with the other's. But I can only think of gradually scaling the smaller one up by very small increments. That seems a little tedious and sub-optimal.

Is there a better way within Python and Maya to match the height of the two bounding boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take the height of the larger object and divide it by the height of the smaller object to get a scale factor to use on the smaller object.

very very simple example (in pseudo code):

```
objectA height = 20  
objectB height = 10  
20 / 10 = 2 (so, scale objectB by 2 to match the height)
```

Your actual code will be a matter of extracting the height from each bounding box, comparing the heights to determine the smaller object and scale factor, and then scaling the smaller one.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Never even thought of this. Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: @john - glad it works for you!  It should also work the opposite way if you need to scale down the larger object

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will scale a given set of objects to the combined bounding box size of a second set of objects. (Works with individual objects as well)

```
def matchScale(to, frm, scale=True):
    '''Scale each of the given objects to the combined bounding box of a second set of objects.

    :Parameters:
        to (str)(obj)(list) = The object(s) to scale.
        frm (str)(obj)(list) = The object(s) to get a bounding box size from.
        scale (bool) = Scale the objects. Else, just return the scale value.

    :Return:
        (list) scale values as [x,y,z,x,y,z...]
    '''
    to = pm.ls(to, flatten=True)
    frm = pm.ls(frm, flatten=True)

    xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax = pm.exactWorldBoundingBox(frm)
    ax, ay, az = aBoundBox = [xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin, zmax-zmin]

    result=[]
    for obj in to:

        xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax = pm.exactWorldBoundingBox(obj)
        bx, by, bz = bBoundBox = [xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin, zmax-zmin]

        oldx, oldy, oldz = bScaleOld = pm.xform(obj, q=1, s=1, r=1)
        diffx, diffy, diffz = boundDifference = [ax/bx, ay/by, az/bz]
        bScaleNew = [oldx*diffx, oldy*diffy, oldz*diffz]
        [result.append(i) for i in bScaleNew]

        if scale:
            pm.xform(obj, scale=bScaleNew)

    return result
```